# Don't use type tests, declare doTheTask?

Tags: java, instance, overriding

I'm going through Java For Everyone by Cay Horstmann.

I'm a bit confused on when it says:

> Don't Use Type Tests

This is about using `instanceof` operator for specific type tests in order to implement behavior that varies with each class like (taken straight from the book):

```
if (q instanceof ChoiceQuestions) //Don't do this
{
   //Do the task the ChoiceQuestion way
}
else if (q instanceof Question)
{
   //Do the task Question way
}
```

Apparently this is a poor way to do it as if you have a new class like `NumericQuestion` added you need to revise all parts of your program that make a type test, adding another case.

It is better to add class `NumericQuestion` to the program. Nothing needs to change as we are using polymorphism, not type tests.
When ever you find yourself trying to use tyepe tests in a hierarchy of classes, reconsider and use polymorphism instead. Declare a method `doTheTask` in the superclass, override it in the subclasses and call `q.doTheTask()`

What I don't understand is the last paragraph, the one above. Can someone shoe me an example of what it means please? (I'm kind of a visual learner). How do we actually do this without using tyep tests?

Comment: This is fundamental polymorphism -- one of the 2-3 main principles behind object-oriented programming.  You need to find a few good articles on polymorphism and study them, then do some "toy" programs to experiment with them to get the concept into your brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that instead of this:

```
if (q instanceof ChoiceQuestions) //Don't do this
{
   //Do the task the ChoiceQuestion way
}
else if (q instanceof Question)
{
   //Do the task Question way
}
```

you should do this:

```
q.doTheTask();
```

where the `Question` class contains:

```
public void doTheTask(String someParameter){
    //Do the task Question way
}
```

and the `ChoiceQuestion` class contains

```
public void doTheTask(String someParameter){
    //Do the task the  ChoiceQuestion way
}
```

Then, when you get a new class `DrawQuestion`, it will contain

```
public void doTheTask(String someParameter){
    //Do the task the DrawQuestionway
}
```

but *none of the code that calls `doTheTask()` will have to change!* There is no risk, as there is with the `if (q instanceof ChoiceQuestions)` pattern, of forgetting to add the new logic. And (this is actually the more important part in the long run) all the logic that concerns a specific kind of `Question` is concentrated in one class rather than spread out across all parts of the app.

Answer (score 1):

What you should understand is that the class is responsible for its behaviour, not the calling part from the exmaple. I learned this as "a table should paint itself" principle:

Visualise furniture. You have a painter class that paints furniture, but you have to "learn" it how to paint a new type of furniture everytime you declare one. So

Painter:

```
if (q instanceof Table) //Don't do this
{
   //paint table
}
else if (q instanceof Closet)
{
   //paint closet
}
```

What you do is that you make all furniture extend a "furniture" class, that knows a method `paintThySelf()`. So now the painter just does

```
q.paintThySelf()
```

And if you add a Chair class, you will have to add the `paintThySelf()` method, and you can have it painted.

Answer (score 0):

As a design principle, favour creating a subclass that has different (overridden) behaviour over using `instanceof` to control behaviour.